# Sending bitcoins from wallet without downloading the blockchain or giving up control

Tags: wallet, blockchain, client

I can generate a bitcoin wallet at bitaddress.org, and I can verify that I have received payments at blockchain.info.

But if I want to send bitcoins from my wallet, I know only of 2 ways:

1. Use Bitcoin-Qt, which needs the blockchain.
2. Use an online wallet, which essentially gives control over my wallet to someone else.

Is there a way to send bitcoins from my wallet without the blockchain, but at the same time, without giving access to my wallet to an outside server **at any point**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an SPV client such as [MultiBit](https://multibit.org/). This does not need the whole blockchain, and does not give up control of your wallet.

Comment: Also there is Electrum: http://electrum.org/

Answer (score 5):

There are so-called light-weight wallets out there operating WITHOUT the need to download the entire blockchain first. MultiBit is one of these (and probably the most commonly used) and is available for the big-3 OSes.